# Error while creating tables on Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I created this table in Hive:

```
hive> CREATE TABLE twitter_data(datePosted TIMESTAMP
  , userId BIGINT
  , userName STRING
  , tweets STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

But it displays this error message:

> FAILED: Error in metadata: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory
>   NestedThrowables:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

Does anyone know what this error message means?

Comment: what is the version of hive you are using?

Comment: A similar issue is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853445/hive-doesnt-work-on-install

Answer (score 0):

I recently met with this problem and the issue was related to the Hive JDBC driver which was not available to the client while making the request to Hive. This is what I did to solve my problem:

1. I did verify that I do have the Hive JDBC connector installed in my cluster
2. I modified the following settings in `hive-site.xml` correctly depending on my local settings:

```xml
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://myhost/metastore</value>
  <description>the URL of the MySQL database</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hive</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>mypassword</value>
</property>
```