# Unable to instantiate HiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hive, hdfs, hue

I have a 3 nodes cluster running hive.
When i try to run some test from outside the cluster i am getting following given below error

> FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
>   FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
>   Logging initialized using configuration in file:/net/slc01nwj/scratch/ashsshar/view_storage/ashsshar_bda_latest_2/work/hive_scratch/conf/hive-log4j.properties

When I login to cluster node and execute hive its working fine.

hive> show  databases ;
OK
default

Following error is genereted in test log files

> 13/04/04 03:10:49 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:ashsshar {my username }(auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Failed to create database '/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db', see the next exception for details.
>   NestedThrowables:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Failed to create database '/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db', see the next exception for details.

My `hive-site.xml` file contains this connection property ::

```
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db;create=true</value>
<description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
```

I have changed the `/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db` at my cluster node, but still getting the same error

I have also tried removing all *lck files from above directory

Answer (score 9):

Does {username} have the permissions to create
`/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db` ?

If it is a test cluster you could do

`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db`

or `chown` it to the user running it.

Comment: HI ..
I have already tried this but still getting the same error

Comment: Please make sure Hadoop is running too.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the $HADOOP_HOME/build folder. I had same problem with hive-0.10.0 or above versions. Then I tried hive-0.9.0 and got a different set of errors. Luckily found this thread [Hive doesn't work on install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853445/hive-doesnt-work-on-install). Tried the same trick and it worked for me magically. I am using default derby db.

Answer (score 1):

this is for permissions issue for hive folder. please de the following will work well.
go to hive user ,for me hduser,
sudo chmod -R 777 hive

Answer (score 1):

This issue occur due to abrupt termination of hive shell. Which created a unattended db.lck file. 
TO resolve this issue,

> browse to your metastore_db location
>   remove the tmp, dbex.lck and db.lck files.
>   Open the hive shell again. It will work.

You can see tmp, dbex.lck and db.lck files get created once again.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after i moved the metastore from /var/lib/hive/. I did that by editing: /etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-site.xml

from:

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db;create=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
```

to:

```
<property>  
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/prashant/hive/metastore/metastore_db;create=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Pls make sure of that whether you have a MetaStore_db in your hadoop directory already, if have, remove it and format your hdfs again,
and then try to start hive

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's privilege problem. Enter your hive shell by following command:

```
sudo -u hdfs hive
```